# R how to convert timestamps into multiple timezones in the same column

Tags: r, posix, unix-timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a dataframe that contains two character variables: one is a timestamp and the other is a US state.
I have been unsuccessfully trying to convert each timestamp to a POSIX object, with time zone assigned according to the corresponding value for state: Eastern Time (EST) for Florida (FL) and Central Time (CST6CDT) for Texas (TX).
However, no matter what I try, R will only return either all of the time stamps in a single time zone or else as a string containing the number of seconds since the origin.
I can of course convert the string to a POSIX object but I come full circle and cannot declare multiple timezones.
I also tried this with a loop instead of indexing but that doesn't work either.

I would be particularly keen to understand what's going on. My guess (perhaps incorrect) is that the problem is to do with the data type declared in a column, as this could explain what happens in Example 3.
 But, no matter what I've read or attempted, I cannot find out how to get this to work.

Example 1 - Converting df$time to a POSIX object and then trying to assign different timezones by df$state

```
 df <- data.frame(time = c("2010-03-05 07:03:00", "2010-03-05 16:00:00", "2010-03-06 07:01:00"), state = c("FL", "FL", "TX"))
df$time <- as.character(df$time); df$state <- as.character(df$state)
df$time <- as.POSIXct (strptime(df$time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
df$time  
#-----
#[1] "2010-03-05 07:03:00 PST" "2010-03-05 16:00:00 PST" "2010-03-06 07:01:00 PST"
```

`df$time` has successfully been converted to a POSIX object.  But when I try to assign time zone by state, the time zone remains in whatever state it was initialized (in my location, that's PST).

```
 df$time[df$state == "FL"] <- as.POSIXct (strptime(df$time[df$state == "FL"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz = "EST" 
 df$time[df$state == "TX"] <- as.POSIXct (strptime(df$time[df$state == "TX"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz = "CST6CDT")
 df$time
#[1] "2010-03-05 04:03:00 PST" "2010-03-05 13:00:00 PST" "2010-03-06 05:01:00 PST"
```

Example 2 - Trying to convert the df$time string directly to each state's time zone *without* first converti

```
ng the string to a POSIX object

 df <- data.frame(time = c("2010-03-05 07:03:00", "2010-03-05 16:00:00", "2010-03-06 07:01:00"), state = c("FL", "FL", "TX"))
 df$time <- as.character(df$time); df$state <- as.character(df$state)
 df$time
#[1] "2010-03-05 07:03:00" "2010-03-05 16:00:00" "2010-03-06 07:01:00"
 df$time[df$state == "FL"] <- as.POSIXct (strptime(df$time[df$state == "FL"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz = "EST")

df$time[df$state == "TX"] <- as.POSIXct (strptime(df$time[df$state == "TX"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz = "CST6CDT")
df$time
[1] "1267790580" "1267822800" "1267880460"
```

Example 3  - Although I *can* take the df$time strings produced by the code in Example 2 and successfully convert them to EST...

```
 as.POSIXct(as.numeric(df$time[df$state == "FL"]), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "EST")

#[1] "2010-03-05 07:03:00 EST" "2010-03-05 16:00:00 EST"
```

# ... but if I try to pass those objects back to the dataframe, R converts them back to a string and I come full circle.

```
 df$time[df$state == "FL"] <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(df$time[df$state == "FL"]), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "EST")
 df$time
#[1] "1267790580" "1267822800" "1267880460"
```

Comment: Well that was a real PITA to edit. Do learn to use the SO markdown formatting features properly and don't excessively bold your presentations. Remove the "thanks in advance" and polite pleas, because those are explicitly deprecated for SO. This is a "just the facts, Ma'am" zone. R does not support mixed timezone vectors. Need to come up with an alternate. The financial people have been doing it for a long time, so I suggest searching. Internally times are all GMT.

Comment: I'm not sure R supports a vector of POSIXct objects with different time zones. Perhaps you can make a "tz" column next to the time column to define what time zone you want it in.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, R cannot handle multiple timezones in a single vector.  So if anybody else is trying to solve the same problem as I was, I can offer a crude but effective workaround.

First, create separate vectors for each time zone and set the POSIX objects to local time in each, then merge the separate vectors into a new vector, with the POSIX objects set to UTC/GMT (or other single time zone of your choosing).

```
df <- data.frame(time = c("2010-03-05 07:03:00", "2010-03-05 16:00:00", "2010-03-05 08:27:00"), state = c("FL", "FL", "TX"))

df$time <- as.character(df$time); df$state <- as.character(df$state)

df$timeFL[df$state == "FL"] <- as.POSIXct (strptime(df$time[df$state == "FL"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz = "EST")

df$timeFL <- as.POSIXct(df$timeFL, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "EST")

df$timeTX[df$state == "TX"] <- as.POSIXct (strptime(df$time[df$state == "TX"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), tz = "CST6CDT")

df$timeTX <- as.POSIXct(df$timeTX, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "CST6CDT")

df$common.time.UTC[!is.na(df$timeFL)] <- df$timeFL[!is.na(df$timeFL)]

df$common.time.UTC[!is.na(df$timeTX)] <- df$timeTX[!is.na(df$timeTX)]

df$common.time.UTC <- as.POSIXct(df$common.time.UTC, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")

df$timeFL <- NULL; df$timeTX <- NULL

df

time                state     common.time.UTC
2010-03-05 07:03:00    FL 2010-03-05 12:03:00
2010-03-05 16:00:00    FL 2010-03-05 21:00:00
2010-03-05 08:27:00    TX 2010-03-05 14:27:00
```