# How to convert a column of UTC timestamps into several different timezones?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, utc

I have a dataset with dates stored in the DB as UTC, however, the timezone is actually different.

```
mydat <- data.frame(
  time_stamp=c("2022-08-01 05:00:00 UTC","2022-08-01 17:00:00 UTC","2022-08-02 22:30:00 UTC","2022-08-04 05:00:00 UTC","2022-08-05 02:00:00 UTC"),
  timezone=c("America/Chicago","America/New_York","America/Los_Angeles","America/Denver","America/New_York")
)
```

I want to apply the timezone to the UTC saved timestamps, over the entire column.

I looked into the `with_tz` function in the lubridate package, but I don't see how to reference the "timezone" column, rather than hardcoding in a value.

Such as if I try

```
with_tz(mydat$time_stamp, tzone = mydat$timezone)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : invalid 'tz' value`
```

However, if I try

```
mydat$time_stamp2 <- with_tz(mydat$time_stamp,"America/New_York")
```

that will render a new column without issue. How can I do this just referencing column values?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40514448/903061) you can't have different timezones in the same vector--hence the `with_tz` and other timezone editing functions only accepting a single timezone.

Comment: Hey Julie can you please unaccept my answer so that I can delete in protest to the obnoxious editing?  Thank you!

Comment: It says it's locked so I can't unaccept right now :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do what you ask for:

#### Code

```
mydat <- data.frame(time_stamp=c("2022-08-01 05:00:00 UTC", 
                                 "2022-08-01 17:00:00 UTC",
                                 "2022-08-02 22:30:00 UTC",
                                 "2022-08-04 05:00:00 UTC", 
                                 "2022-08-05 02:00:00 UTC"),
                    timezone=c("America/Chicago", "America/New_York", 
                               "America/Los_Angeles", "America/Denver",
                               "America/New_York"))

mydat$utc <- anytime::utctime(mydat$time_stamp, tz="UTC")
mydat$format <- ""
for (i in seq_len(nrow(mydat)))
    mydat[i, "format"] <- strftime(mydat[i,"utc"], 
                                   "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                                   tz=mydat[i,"timezone"])
```

#### Output

```
> mydat
               time_stamp            timezone                 utc              format
1 2022-08-01 05:00:00 UTC     America/Chicago 2022-08-01 05:00:00 2022-08-01 00:00:00
2 2022-08-01 17:00:00 UTC    America/New_York 2022-08-01 17:00:00 2022-08-01 13:00:00
3 2022-08-02 22:30:00 UTC America/Los_Angeles 2022-08-02 22:30:00 2022-08-02 15:30:00
4 2022-08-04 05:00:00 UTC      America/Denver 2022-08-04 05:00:00 2022-08-03 23:00:00
5 2022-08-05 02:00:00 UTC    America/New_York 2022-08-05 02:00:00 2022-08-04 22:00:00
>
```

#### Comment

We first parse your data as UTC, I once wrote a helper function for that in my [anytime](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) package (there are alternatives but this is how I do it...).  We then need to format from the given (numeric !!) UTC representation to the give timezone. We need a loop for this as the `tz` argument to `strftime()` is not vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

Dirk gave a great answer that uses (mostly) base R tooling, if that is a requirement of yours. I wanted to also add an answer that uses the [clock](https://clock.r-lib.org) package that I developed because it doesn't require working rowwise over your data frame. clock has a function called [`sys_time_info()`](https://clock.r-lib.org/reference/sys_time_info.html) that retrieves low level information about a UTC time point in a specific time zone. It is one of the few functions where it makes sense to have a vectorized `zone` argument (which you need here) and returns an `offset` from UTC that will be useful here for converting to a "local" time.

As others have mentioned, you won't be able to construct a date-time vector that stores multiple time zones in it, but if you just need to see what the local time would have been in those zones, this can still be useful.

```r
library(clock)

mydat <- data.frame(
  time_stamp=c("2022-08-01 05:00:00 UTC","2022-08-01 17:00:00 UTC","2022-08-02 22:30:00 UTC","2022-08-04 05:00:00 UTC","2022-08-05 02:00:00 UTC"),
  timezone=c("America/Chicago","America/New_York","America/Los_Angeles","America/Denver","America/New_York")
)

# Parse into a "sys-time" type, which can be thought of as a UTC time point
mydat$time_stamp <- sys_time_parse(mydat$time_stamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
mydat
#>            time_stamp            timezone
#> 1 2022-08-01T05:00:00     America/Chicago
#> 2 2022-08-01T17:00:00    America/New_York
#> 3 2022-08-02T22:30:00 America/Los_Angeles
#> 4 2022-08-04T05:00:00      America/Denver
#> 5 2022-08-05T02:00:00    America/New_York

# "Low level" information about DST, the time zone abbreviation,
# and offset from UTC in that zone. This is one of the few functions where
# it makes sense to have a vectorized `zone` argument.
info <- sys_time_info(mydat$time_stamp, mydat$timezone)
info
#>                 begin                 end offset  dst abbreviation
#> 1 2022-03-13T08:00:00 2022-11-06T07:00:00 -18000 TRUE          CDT
#> 2 2022-03-13T07:00:00 2022-11-06T06:00:00 -14400 TRUE          EDT
#> 3 2022-03-13T10:00:00 2022-11-06T09:00:00 -25200 TRUE          PDT
#> 4 2022-03-13T09:00:00 2022-11-06T08:00:00 -21600 TRUE          MDT
#> 5 2022-03-13T07:00:00 2022-11-06T06:00:00 -14400 TRUE          EDT

# Add the offset to the sys-time and then convert to a character column
# (these times don't really represent sys-time anymore since they are now localized)
mydat$localized <- as.character(mydat$time_stamp + info$offset)
mydat
#>            time_stamp            timezone           localized
#> 1 2022-08-01T05:00:00     America/Chicago 2022-08-01T00:00:00
#> 2 2022-08-01T17:00:00    America/New_York 2022-08-01T13:00:00
#> 3 2022-08-02T22:30:00 America/Los_Angeles 2022-08-02T15:30:00
#> 4 2022-08-04T05:00:00      America/Denver 2022-08-03T23:00:00
#> 5 2022-08-05T02:00:00    America/New_York 2022-08-04T22:00:00
```